# Any framework /tools / library that can import 3d object(with animation)?

Tags: android, animation, frameworks, 3d

I noticed that there is a few framework (such as min3d) that capable of importing 3d object (.obj) into android. My question is there any way to import a 3d object that already have an animation set into it? For example, I have 3d studio max software that allows me to create a 3D object and include animation into it. The outcome of the file if not mistaken is .fbx file (with animation in it).

Is there any way to process this 3D object with its animation and display out in android devices?

Please do share with me if there is something like this or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Rajawali](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2011/08/23/announcing-rajawali-an-opengl-es-2-0-based-3d-framework-for-android/) (the successor of min3d), it supports loading .fbx files.